# D7: Create an administration page for my module

Tags: users

I have a custom module that sends an email with an order to the customer. I hardcoded the email body text in a string inside the module code but my client want to have control over it and I need to create an admin page for him:
[image]

I need to save it and use that text as a variable.

I started the page like this:

```
function shop_admin_settings($form, &$form_state) {
     $form = array();
     $form['mail_template'] = array(
       '#type' => 'fieldset',
       '#title' => t('Shop Email Template'),
       '#colapsed' => FALSE,
       '#collapsible' => TRUE,  
     );

     $form['mail_template']['body'] = array(
       '#type' => 'textarea',
       '#title'  => t('Email template'),
       '#rows' => 10,  
     );
     return system_settings_form($form);
 }
```

and use hook_mail_alter to append `$form['mail_template']['body']` to the existing email body

```
function shop_mail_alter(&$message, $form_state) {
$client_body = $form_state['mail_template']['body']
if (is_array($message['body'])) {
    $message['body'][] .= $client_body;
  }
}
```

Now if you please help me, I am a bit stuck:

1. I need to retrieve the body provided by client, I don't know how (my code is not correct)
2. Do I need to create a separate admin.inc in order to work? Or do I simply need to add a menu path like admin/config/system/shop and a corresponding callback?
3. Is it possible for client to use tokens inside the body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all [hook_mail_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) only has 1 parameter, no `$form_state`. Second of all, the [system_settings_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form_submit/7) will save the form values into the variables table in the database. To access that value you should use [variable_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7).

Now, your code should look like this:

```
// try to change body to something more specific to your module, like custom_email_body
$form['mail_template']['custom_email_body'] = array( 
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title'  => t('Email template'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('custom_email_body', ''),
  '#rows' => 10,  
);
```

then:

```
function shop_mail_alter(&$message) {
$client_body = variable_get('custom_email_body', '');
if (is_array($message['body'])) {
    $message['body'][] .= $client_body;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but sadly system_settings_form() does not save any form content and also ['custom_email_body'] form field does not keep persistent info.

Comment: to display existing value in form, change $form['mail_template']['custom_email_body'] and add property `'#default_value' = variable_get('custom_email_body', '');`

Answer (score 0):

for point 2) you are correct you need to create one custom menu hook in custom module
in that hook

```
   $items['admin/config/system/shop'] = array(
       'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
    'page arguments' => array('shop_admin_settings'), //put the name of the form here
    'access callback' => TRUE
    );
```